# I'm trying to store a decimal number in a postgres database in flask using sqlalchemy and the number is rounded

Tags: python, flash, flask-sqlalchemy

Im trying to save a price variable in sqlalchmey but if its 78.6 it rounds up to 79.0

I've tried numeric and float datatypes and I'm using a postgresql heroku database

```
db.Column(db.Float(precision=1,asdecimal=False,decimal_return_scale=None))
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `asdecimal` attribute as `True` instead of `False`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Float), the precision is the total number of digits of the values you want to store, so you should increment that number, as currently its value is 1, so I imagine the rounding problem is due to that. Moreover, it is not recommended to store currency values as float, due to rounding problems with floating point. Check some of these articles ([art1](https://medium.com/@cancerian0684/which-data-type-would-you-choose-for-storing-currency-values-like-trading-price-dd7489e7a439), [art2](https://cardinalby.github.io/blog/post/best-practices/storing-currency-values-data-types/)). You should use either integers to store cents, or `db.Decimal(precision=10, scale=2,...)`, which does not have loss of precision.